# Use of <is based on>

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to say that the criterion of airfoil selection is according to this reference [72]. So, Is the use of "is based on" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> Therefore, in the present work, the criterion of airfoil selection at the tip section (NACA0020) for the VTB Wells turbine design **is
>   based on** this reference [72].

Comment: Could you expand on *according to*? As used it seems to indicate a vague relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When describing criteria, use *for*. Using *is based on* is correct.

> Therefore, in the present work, the criterion **for** airfoil selection at the tip section (NACA0020), **used in** the VTB Wells turbine design, is based on this reference [72].

I added *used in* to avoid using *for* multiple times. After all, we're still describing the criterion: it's used in the design.

Answer (score 1):

No, it just means that "this reference [72]." had some historical value in the current product.

For example, if the Boeing 747 was designed by making improvements on the Boeing 707, then you could say:

> The design of the Boeing 747 **was based on** design of the Boeing 707.

They are obviously not the same or very similar.